# In Cell editing does not update value on focus change

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Cell value is not captured when mouse focus changes

I have a simple datatable that shows the name and income. The cell values are editable. When I update the cell value with a different value and hit "Update" (basically change mouse focus) the new value is not captured. The update method 
prints the old value. However, when I press the "tab" key I can see the updated values printed. I am not sure what I am missing

Here is my backing bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {        
    NVPair nvp = new NVPair("xx", 10000);
    dataList.add(nvp);
    nvp = new NVPair("yy", 20000);
    dataList.add(nvp);
}

public void update() {
    for (NVPair item : dataList) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + item.getName() + " Value: " + 
item.getValue());
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
 <h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="testTable" value="#{testBean.dataList}" var="item"
                editable="true" editMode="cell">
                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{testBean.onCellEdit}"
                    immediate="true" update="testTable" />


                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Income">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton action="#{testBean.update}" value="Update" />
        </h:form>
```

When the focus changes, I am expecting that the edited value is captured just like when the tab key is pressed.